# Start session edit on a specific layer on the map?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, editing, arcobjects

I created a GIS using ArcObjects, my application needs to be connected with a geodatabase stored in SQL Server. I used ARCSDE to connect my application to the database and when the database is connected, my application loads two tables - the first one is called `Commune` and the second one is called `Parcelle`. Their `esriDatasetType` is:
`esriDatasetType.esriDTFeatureClass`.

A Parcelle belongs to only one Commune; and a Commmune can contain many Parcelles.

What I want to do is start the session and edit the Parcelle layer without the possibility to edit the Commune layer. When I use my code, I can edit both layers in the map:

```
public static void Start(IEngineEditor _engineEditor, IMapControl4 map, string targetLayerName)
{
    //If an edit session has already been started, exit.
    if (_engineEditor.EditState == esriEngineEditState.esriEngineStateEditing) return;

    //Start editing the workspace of the first feature layer found.
    for (int layerCounter = 0; layerCounter <= map.LayerCount - 1; layerCounter++)
    {
        ILayer currentLayer = map.get_Layer(layerCounter);
        if (currentLayer.Name != targetLayerName) continue;
        try
        {
            if (currentLayer is IFeatureLayer)
            {
                IFeatureLayer featureLayer = currentLayer as IFeatureLayer;
                IDataset dataset = featureLayer.FeatureClass as IDataset;
                IWorkspace workspace = dataset.Workspace;
                _engineEditor.StartEditing(workspace, map.ActiveView.FocusMap);

                ((IEngineEditLayers)_engineEditor).SetTargetLayer(featureLayer, 0);
                break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Dialog.info("Info", ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

My function has 3 parameters: `IEngineEditor`, `IMapControl4` and the name of the layer that I want to edit, which is the layer Parcelle in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i found a solution, i've just set the `IFeatureLayer.Selectable = false` for the `ILayer` Commune and it's working great.